# How to get raspberry pi 4 to read a line-in input from a sound card

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, soundcard

I want my Raspberry pi to read the audio off of my main computer and then make some adafruit neopixel lights that I have connected change brightness in correlation to how loud the audio is. The coding (probably) will not be an issue, but I can not figure out how to get the Raspberry pi to read my sound card with a line-in input correctly. For reference, I am using a raspberry pi 4 and the sound card I am using is a ICUSBAUDIO7D.

Comment: You might get better answers over at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.